# HTML Combine Two IMG tags into One

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a form that works well in Internet Explorer but not in Firefox or Chrome.

I have an image then when clicked (onmousedown) changes the image source (goes to another IMG tag and changes the source, let's call it IMG2). However, in Internet Explorer, it returns to the original IMG tag and completes the onmouseup function. In Firefox, it seems stuck at the second IMG2 tag and doesn't return to the original IMG.

The onmouseup function actually submits the form so it now gets stuck with a changed image, but the page just stays stationary and doesn't go anywhere. I was wondering if maybe what I think the problem is wrong, or if there is a way I can do the below code in one image tag.

Thanks for any help in advance!

```
<IMG id="ApproveUp"   SRC="[LL_SUPPORTPATH /]ApproveUp.png" onMouseDown="this.style.display='none';document.getElementById('ApproveDown1').style.display='';" onMouseUp="document.myForm._1_1_62_1.value='Approved';document.getElementById('_1_1_69_1').value=document.getElementById('_1_1_64_1_SavedName').value.substring(0,document.getElementById('_1_1_64_1_SavedName').value.indexOf('('));doSubmit(document.myForm)">
<IMG id="ApproveDown1"  SRC="[LL_SUPPORTPATH /]ApproveDown.png" style="display:none">
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen when you click the images?

Comment: Hi Psioniax, I expect the image to change to another image and the form to submit. Some of the other functions (ex 1_62_1=Approved) change some of the values in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.src` to set the image to the Down.png in your original mousedown call.

```
<IMG id="ApproveUp" SRC="[LL_SUPPORTPATH /]ApproveUp.png" onMouseDown="this.src = '[LL_SUPPORTPATH /]ApproveDown.png'; this.style.display='none'; document.getElementById('ApproveDown1').style.display='';" onMouseUp="document.myForm._1_1_62_1.value='Approved';document.getElementById('_1_1_69_1').value=document.getElementById('_1_1_64_1_SavedName').value.substring(0,document.getElementById('_1_1_64_1_SavedName').value.indexOf('('));doSubmit(document.myForm)">
```

as for why the form doesn't submit, you didn't supply the code of doSubmit().   it's possible it does get called but is broken in there.